# Is this diagram wrong as the congruent circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, short-circuit

Given the below diagram.

[image]

The 2 identities are given.

$$
V_{1}=AV_{2}+BI_{2}
$$

$$
I_{1}=CV_{2}+DI_{2}
$$

$$
A,B,C,D~\text{are constant coefficients.}
$$

As \$V_{2}=0~\$

\$V_{1}=BI_{2}\$

\$I_{1}=DI_{2}\$

the above circuit is congruent with the below diagram.

[image]

Hence,

\$V_1=r_3I_2\$

\$V_1=r_1(I_1-I_2)\$

These statements are given from the textbook.

The problem for me is that why the pre position of \$r_2\$ was shortened in the second diagram.

I think that as \$V_2=0\$ then any current doesn't flow between the endpoints of \$r_2\$ so this part must be opened,not be shortened.

Is the second diagram incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second diagram is correct, because imposing \$V_2=0\$ means that no voltage drops across that portion of the circuit and such a condition is obtained indeed by short-circuiting \$r_2\$. This condition **does not** imply no current flow, and in fact \$I_2\$ flows through \$r_3\$, down into the shorted branch (by-passing \$r_2\$ and thus avoiding any voltage drop across it) and back towards the negative "side" of \$V_1\$, where it is combined with \$I_1-I_2\$ correctly yielding \$I_1\$.

Put it another way, if you actually opened your rightmost branch, then no current would flow through *neither* \$r_2\$ or \$r_3\$, but \$V_2=V_1\neq0\$ would hold and contradict your starting \$V_2=0\$ assumption.

Summarizing:

- \$I=0\$ --> open circuit
- \$V=0\$ --> short circuit

Answer (score 0):

> *Is the second diagram incorrect?*

The 2nd diagram has the \$V_2\$ port shorted out hence \$V_2 = 0\$. There is no other way to make \$V_2 = 0\$ other than by shorting it out (or making \$r_3\$ infinity) hence, the 2nd diagram is correct.

If you made \$r_3\$ infinity then it doesn't help you progress the problem because \$I_2\$ becomes zero.